# Error in setting the path variable in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, gnu-toolchain

I would like to set a path to the Gnu toolchain downloaded from https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads. I used the line
$PATH=$HOME/Toolchains/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update/bin:$PATH to set the path in the terminal.
For the first time, I was able to change the path, then I closed the terminal and again set the (wrong) path $PATH=/home/paulson/Toolchains/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update/bin:$PATH. Now I am unable to set the correct path and the terminal shows as below.

```
paulson@debian:~/Toolchains$ 

paulson@debian:~/Toolchains$ ls
gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update

paulson@debian:~/Toolchains$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

paulson@debian:~/Toolchains$ $PATH=$HOME/Toolchains/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update/bin:$PATH
bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games=/home/paulson/Toolchains/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Do not put `$` on variable when setting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *set* the path environment variable, you need to use:
`export PATH=/some/path:$PATH`.

In your case, it would look like:
`export PATH=$HOME/Toolchains/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update/bin:$PATH`
The only downside to setting the path manually is that it **will not persist across bash sessions**. If you want this change to be permanent, then I would suggest adding that line to your `.bashrc` or `.profile` file in the home directory.